# Link button is not working while editing a post in Firefox

Tags: posts, links, tinymce

One of our admins started experiencing a weird issue when editing a post.  When the link button is clicked inside the post editor in visual mode, the box appears with the content inside, but it is grayed out and nothing is clickable.  This is only currently happening in Firefox.  I already instructed the admin to clear the cache, logout/login, restart the computer, etc, but nothing has seemed to do the trick.  Any ideas?

**Edit**: For reference, here is a picture of the grayed out link box https://i.stack.imgur.com/EatON.jpg

Comment: There are too few details to make a guess here. Can this be replicated in another browser? Another computer? Are there any errors in browser console? Does disabling plugins and switching to default theme fixes it? Such debug issues typically next to impossible to solve without hands-on approach.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and you're completely correct -- There aren't enough details. This is happening on our editors machine and unfortunately I don't have access to it. I was hoping that perhaps someone experienced something similar, and had a solution or at least a cause.